# how to del tup[3] in formated list to print calendar type output?

Tags: python, leap-year

please copy and save this code.py and enter (without quotes) a day such as "Mer" and then a non leap year like 2019 and notice leap day is still showing up in the print out. i need to delete tuple [3] if it is a leap year and then let it print the 'tup' list after tuple[3] has been excluded from the list

**EDIT CHANGING ALL EDITS MENTIONED BY CONFIRMED ANSWERER RESULTED IN GOOD CODE AND I FOUND THAT THE BUG WAS I MISVALUED LEAP DAY RANGE AS 70 WHEN IT SHOULD BE 69 IN ORDER TO GET THE CODE WORKING. THANK YOU.**

```
 import numpy as np
 def make_calendar(year, start_day):
    tup =   [('Early Winter', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Winter 37,', range(37, 1, + 1)),
            ('Late Winter   ', range(38, 71, + 1)),
            ('Leap Day      ', range(70, 69 + 1)),#tup[3] is this line i need to delete if not leap year
            ('Late Winter   ', range(71, 74, + 1)),   
            ('Early Spring  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Spring 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Spring   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Summer  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Summer 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Summer   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Autumn  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Autumn 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Autumn   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Fall    ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Fall 37,  ', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Fall     ', range(38, 74, + 1))];
    week = ['Mer', 'Ven', 'Ear', 'Mar', 'Jup', 'Sat', 'Ura', 'Nep', 'Plu']
    start_pos = week.index(start_day)
    def is_leap(year): 
        if (not year%4 and year%100 or not year%400): # algorithm to determine leap year
            return True
    if not is_leap(year):
        del tup[3]
    for month, days in tup: 
    # Print month title
        print('{0} {1}'.format(month, year).center(20, ' '))
        # Print Day headings
        print(''.join(['{0:<3}'.format(w) for w in week]))
        # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
        print('{0:<3}'.format('')*start_pos, end='')

        for day in days:
            # Print day
            print('{0!s:<3}'.format(day), end='')
            start_pos += 1
            if start_pos == 9:
                # If start_pos == 9 (Sunday) start new line
                print()
                start_pos = 0 # Reset counter
        print('\n')
start_day=(input('Enter start day of the year Mer,Ven,Ear,Mar,Jup,Sat,Ura,Nep,Plu'))
year=int(input('Enter Year'))       
make_calendar(year, start_day)
```

this is a program that breaks down the calendar into equal units i think its cool but no matter what i do the tuple[3] does not work. please if someone can teach me more about tuples or why this isnt working i would be very greatfull. even if you dont know i appreciate you taking the time out of your day to read my problem.

Comment: Hint: what is `year`? Where does it come from? Print out the value and you may be able to narrow down your error.

Comment: This code does not exhibit the claimed error.  It would if `is_leap()` were ever called, but it isn't.  That function is _defined_ but never _called_.  Are you sure this is the actual code?

Comment: As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question isn't ready for asking here yet, since you first need to extract a [mcve], which is the reason it's probably going to be closed.

Comment: year is coming from the input entered. example 2019
however the calendar is not being printed properly. the  if is_leap(year): return false del tup[3]  ... function is still not returning with the desired output which would print the calendar without '('Leap Day      ', range(70, 70, + 1)),' on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely related to this line of code:

```
year=int(input('Enter Year')),
```

The trailing comma means that `year` is a *tuple*, not a plain integer.

If the function `is_leap()` were ever called, then it would demonstrate the stated error behavior.

However, I must point out that the `is_leap()` function is *defined* but it is never *called*, so I have to think that you haven't shown us the genuine code.

#### UPDATE:

According to your post, this is the definition of `is_leap()`:

```
def is_leap(year): 
    if (not year%4 and year%100 or not year%400): # **algorithm to determine leap year**
        return True
    if is_leap(year):
        return False
        del tup[3] #**it still prints 2019
```

As you can see, the call to `is_leap()` is contained *within the function itself*, and since that is the only call to that function in the entire code, it is never called.

Perhaps this is an indentation error, and the `if is_leap(year)` block is actually meant to be outdented one level?

Comment: how would i call the is_leap to get the calendar to print without leap day? the code is printing fine the error is not showing up anymore but its simply printing without del tup[3] in the condition is_leap(year) flase

Comment: i unindented if is_leap(year) and the del tup[3] is still being ignored and is not returning the 2019 calendar . it is still printing the leap year calendar that features the leap day line [3] of the tup

Comment: Update the question with your current code.  And I'll say again that the original code _could not_ have had the claimed error, so somehow you must have posted the wrong code.

Comment: sorry. i updated the code. the error is gone so i edited the question and code to the current updated version. function if is_leap(year) still is not returning del tup(3) if false. also the year is defined as the input type on the second to last line but somehow is not functioning through the if is_leap(year) return false del tup[3]

Comment: UPDATE I GOT IT WORKING YOU WERE RIGHT THANK YOU!! +REP